# Create XML with Swift and KissXML: example?

Tags: ios, swift, xml

I am trying to build an XML document for iOS using KissXML (https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML.git).

Supposedly this is a drop-in replacement for the NSXML class cluster from Apple, which is only available on Mac and not on iOS. It is said to be an almost complete and robust implementation of NSXML for iOS.

I have KissXML installed in my Xcode project. I think correctly, since after `import KissXML` I can `print(KissXMLVersionNumber)` and get `1.0.`

But try as I may, I can not create an XML document from scratch. I am not sure how to understand "drop-in replacement". For example, Apple's `NSXMLDocument` has a `setRootElement()` method, but `XMLDocument` from KissXML does not. Perhaps I am missing the obvious. Can anyone provide a simple example of how to go about it? The xml expression I am trying to build for practice is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg>
<svg width="220px" height="120px"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <text font-size="32"  x="25" y="60">
           Hello, World!
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I am on Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2.

Example of what I expect should work, and does not:

First, code for a Cocoa app for MacOS. This uses the native NSXMLDocument class (now renamed to XMLDocument, as XCode tells me; I cannot use NSXMLDocument in my code). It is the complete code for a ViewController class:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let xmlElement = XMLElement(name: "name", stringValue: "value")
        let xmlDoc = XMLDocument(rootElement: xmlElement)
        print("\(xmlDoc.stringValue!)")
    }
}
```

The output of this program is "value", as expected.

Now the same program for a single view app for iOS, using KissXML as a drop-in replacement:

```
import UIKit
import KissXML
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let xmlElement = XMLElement(name: "name", stringValue: "value")
        let xmlDoc = XMLDocument(rootElement: xmlElement)
        print("\(xmlDoc.stringValue!)")
    }
}
```

This program will not compile. At line 8, where xmlDoc is defined, XCode tells me `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'XMLDocument' with an argument list of type '(rootElement: XMLElement)'`.

(The Inspector for XMLDocument tells me `typealias XMLDocument = DDXMLDocument`, and this in turn points me inside the KissXML framework for its definition. So, it is indeed a KissXML class. In the MacOS case, it simply says `class XMLDocument : XMLNode`, which points inside Foundation/NSXMLDocument.)

To make sure KissXML is properly installed, I ran the following program:

```
import UIKit
import KissXML
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("\(KissXMLVersionNumber)")
    }
}
```

This program runs, and outputs "1.0".

Comment: You don't need any library to create XML. XML is just text. The library would be much more useful for parsing XML, not generating XML.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. But using a library makes it much less error prone. Besides, I may want to access the expression later to change some of its elements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130593/swift-nsxml-need-need-to-loop-to-create-mult-children

Comment: Thanks again, tried that also.But NSXMLDocument is not in the iOS libraries, only in the OSX libraries. That is why I asked this question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: But KissXML provides those classes.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know they don't have the same methods. And what they have, I do not understand how to use. Could you perhaps help me with an example?

Comment: KissXML is a drop-in replacement for NSXML. It has the same classes and same API. The link I gave you is an example.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see it. Why don't you show it to me by providing the KissXML code for my little example XML? That's what Stackoverflow is for, isn't it?

Comment: I showed you already. Install KissXML as documented on their website and look at the link I gave you earlier for an example of using the provided KissXML classes which are nearly identical to NSXML.

Comment: I did all that. Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that KissXML is no longer a drop-in replacement for NSXML, due to evolution of NSXML since KissXML was developed.
There must be a way to achieve what I want, but since the only documentation is a reference to NSXML it is of no apparent use. 
I turned to AEXML, which satisfies my needs very well.